# What should I do after getting a DMCA report about a post on my site?

Tags: copyright, blogger, dmca

I am running a website on Blogger. Yesterday, I got a DMCA report about a post. Is it important and what should I do?

Comment: Yes it is important. You should remove the post immediately assuming you did not write it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely aware of the source of the material.  Assuming that the DMCA notice is genuine, and only you can determine that, you should remove the identified content immediately unless you have deep pockets and are willing to take on the claimant in court.

Even before that happens, a complaint is likely to be made to your hosting company who will remove the post.  So beat them to it, take it down.

Comment: Not trying to be a snot, but the host will remove the site and not the post. Just to be clear. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc No problem at all...me being specific rather than more general.

Comment: His host is Blogger, aka Google.   The DMCA notice is their process for giving notice about the issue.